# Change namespace in XmlDOcument in C#

Tags: c#, xml

How can I change the namespace in a XmlDocument as below in C#. I can change the innerxml with string.Replace. But is there any better way to do it.

```
<Result xmlns:Result="MyProject.Result">
    <Result:Errors>
        <Result:Error>
            <Result:Severity>0</Result:Severity>
            <Result:Reason>The input was wrong</Result:Reason>
        </Result:Error>
    </Result:Errors>
</Result>
<Result xmlns:Result="Project.User.Result">
    <Result:Errors>
        <Result:Error>
            <Result:Severity>0</Result:Severity>
            <Result:Reason>The input was wrong</Result:Reason>
        </Result:Error>
    </Result:Errors>
</Result>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the namespace by rewriting the xml using [XmlSerializer-Overloads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/65k4wece(v=vs.110).aspx) that allow this.

```
public class Location { public string L; }
public class MyData { public Location[] Locations { get; set; } }

internal class Program
{
  static void Main ()
  {
    // testdata
    var m = new MyData { Locations = new Location[2] { new Location { L = "L1" }, new Location { L = "L2" } } };

    // simple Serializer
    var xs = new XmlSerializer (typeof (MyData));

    DoSerialize (m, xs);
    Console.WriteLine ();

    var xs2 = new XmlSerializer (typeof (MyData), new XmlAttributeOverrides (), new Type[] { }, new XmlRootAttribute { Namespace = "MyNewNamspace" }, "");

    DoSerialize (m, xs2);
    Console.ReadLine ();
  }


  static void DoSerialize (MyData m, XmlSerializer xs)
  {
    var settings = new XmlWriterSettings
    {
      OmitXmlDeclaration = true,
      Indent = true,
      NewLineOnAttributes = true
    };

    var sww = new System.IO.StringWriter ();
    var writer = XmlWriter.Create (sww, settings);
    xs.Serialize (writer, m);
    Console.WriteLine (sww.ToString ().Replace ("><", ">\r\n<"));
  }
}
```

Comment: This would mean I have to create a class that matches the xml, right?

Comment: @Ramki yes. If you do not have an class structure in place, these [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11103615/how-to-change-xml-namespace-of-certain-element) is probably better suited

Answer (score 0):

You can try,

```
((XmlElement)doc.FirstChild).SetAttribute("xmlns:Result", "Project.User.Result") ;
```